# How can I filter same content in page

Tags: filters, templates

I have website in wordpress have 2 pages Catalogues and Projects. The problem as the content is the same in both pages, so I would like the administrator can select what content goes in each page, https://alliance-production.com/projets-2/

I don't know if this is possible only in php code or have plugin to do this. Maybe have a code to add in template page of Catalogues to show only content on selected especific category in taxonomy, I don't know.

Heres the code of template Catalogues.

```php
<?php Insight::page_title(); ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area row">
            <div id="main" class="main col-md-12 project-list-style">
                <?php
                $paged     = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $args      = array(
                    'post_type' => 'ic_project',
                    'paged'     => $paged
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'components/content', 'catalogue' );
                    }
                    Insight::paging_nav( $the_query );
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                } else {
                    get_template_part( 'components/content', 'none' );
                }
                ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE!  Please provide a bit more information.  For example: You have provided the code template for the catalog, but how is it different from the "Projects" page? Does your "ic_project" CPT support tags or categories? Would you want your content separated by tags or categories, or would you want an admin to individually setup specific entries for each page (hand-picked)?  With more information, you will receive better answers.  You might also check this out:  ["How do I ask a good question"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Good luck!

Comment: Hey there, what do you mean for filter?